# sql server mdx EXISTING

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I am learning the book 'MDX step by step'. I am following the examples and have this question regarding how to understand EXISTING. I understand (I think) 1 and 2 below, but don't understand 3.

Note: The screen shots are not complete but you can get the idea.

1 It returns top 5 Reseller Sales of all products, and just cross join with 4 categories, which is not desired. You can see the top 5 products are repeating.

```
    SELECT
    {([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])} ON COLUMNS,      
    ([Product].[Category].[Category].Members) *
    Generate(
        {[Product].[Category].[Category].Members},
         TopCount(
             {[Product].[Product].[Product].Members},
            5,
            ([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
        ),
        ALL
    ) ON ROWS
    FROM [Step-by-Step]
```

[image]

2 now I add EXISTING, and it returns top 5 reseller sales for each of four categories, which is correct.

```
    SELECT
    {([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])} ON COLUMNS,      
    ([Product].[Category].[Category].Members) *
    Generate(
        {[Product].[Category].[Category].Members},
         TopCount(
             EXISTING {[Product].[Product].[Product].Members},
            5,
            ([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
        ),
        ALL
    ) ON ROWS
    FROM [Step-by-Step]
```

[image]

3 Now this is my question. I put EXISTING on Topcount, how to understand what happened?

```
    SELECT
    {([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])} ON COLUMNS,      
    ([Product].[Category].[Category].Members) *
    Generate(
        {[Product].[Category].[Category].Members},
        EXISTING TopCount(
            {[Product].[Product].[Product].Members},
            5,
            ([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
        ),
        ALL
    ) ON ROWS
    FROM [Step-by-Step]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MDX operator Existing](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Existing.html) is changing the context of cell evaluation locally. It doesn't go 'deeper' into functions or measures. In your last scenario it only has effect on the result of the TopCount, which has no effect as there is nothing to evaluate.

It's a pity that is not a function that changes the tuple context, something like :

```
 CubeContext( ...)  -> where ... is evaluated witht the slicer.
```

Comment: I can see the EXISTING has no effect in 3. But how to understand why it only returns 5 results instead of 20 like as in 1?

Comment: ups, missed that. This is strange, indeed